# Delete contents not within Date Range

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a chunk of information and I had some input in the form of a Start and End date columns. What I want to do is say if your outside of chosen date range then delete contents of the cells, 3 to the right and -4 to the left of each. so -4 to the left of the start date and 3 to the right of end date.

I started but I was having trouble with the delete if your not in my date range to the cells

```
Private Sub cmdFilter_Click()
' Function to filter dates between text boxes, deletes all not in the range


Dim stStart As String, stEnd As String
Dim dbStart As Double, dbEnd As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
'Turn off screen updating until process done so it doesnt flicker

stStart = txtStart.Value
stEnd = txtEnd.Value

If Not IsDate(stStart) Or Not IsDate(stEnd) Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Dates", vbExclamation, "Input Error"
    GoTo ExitSub
End If

dbStart = CDbl(CDate(stStart))
dbEnd = CDbl(CDate(stEnd))


' change to highlight cell for time being

INSERT DELETE IF OUT OF RANGE HERE? 

ExitSub:
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub
```

thanks in advance

Comment: There are 2 methods that you can follow. 1) Autofilter the range depending on your criteria and then clear the cells based on the resulting range (Faster method). 2) Looping and then checking if the dates fall between the range (Slower method)

Comment: @Siddarth Rout: Do you have an example of the faster method with the practice above?
Start column = AE, end column = AF.

Comment: @Zenaphor Use the macro recorder to see what code is generated when you apply the Autofilter for the two columns in question. I would use the filter to show **what will be deleted**, then use ctrl+arrow keys, to select the visible cells and delete their values. I would modify the code for the deletion after Autofilter is applied found [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=56802) Basically, make a range from `.Offset(0,-4)` to `.Offset(0,3)` and append `.Clear` to remove the contents.

Comment: @Zenaphor: Yes check this :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319096/excel-error-when-i-use-specialcells-of-autofilter-to-get-visible-cells-in-vba/10319230#10319230

Comment: @Zenaphor: What does your data sheet look like?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete the entire rows you can do that using SpecialCells with a formula in an extra column that throws an error ...

I think I saw that on the website of Excel MVP Ron De Bruin: [SpecialCells](http://www.rondebruin.nl/specialcells.htm)

is that what you're looking for?