# How to copy a line in excel using a specific word and pasting to another excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have checked a bunch of different posts and can't seem to find the exact code I am looking for. Also I have never used *VBA* before so I'm trying to take codes from other posts and input my info for it to work. No luck yet. At work we have a payroll system in *Excel*. I am trying to search for my name `"Clarke, Matthew"` and then copy that row and paste it to the workbook I have saved on my desktop `"Total hours"`.

Comment: If you are searching for the keyword on a single column (for example, all "`Clarke, Matthew`" are on column A), then the filter feature of Excel should work.

Comment: Perhaps posting what you've got so for would give us a better place to start helping.  You might also look into the `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319096/error-when-i-use-specialcells-of-autofilter-to-get-visible-cells-in-vba/10319230#10319230 modify it to suit your needs :)

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition/11317372#11317372

Comment: @SiddharthRout Your answer to this very question worked for me.  From Google to working macro in 2 minutes, your links notwithstanding!

Answer (score 23):

**CODE**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long '<~~ Not Integer. Might give you error in higher versions of excel
    Dim strSearch As String
    
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("yourSheetName")
    
    strSearch = "Clarke, Matthew"
    
    With ws1

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> I am assuming that the names are in Col A
        '~~> if not then change A below to whatever column letter
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       
        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With
        
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    '~~> Destination File
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If
    
        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With
    
    wb2.Save
    wb2.Close
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: TY for all the feed back. I am tryng to use that second macro but am now recieving an error message on this line .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*" .... Tells me 'Run time error 1004: Autofilter method of range failed'. Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you set here? `With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
`?

Comment: I had left that the same, than i tried A1:A50 assuming it meant the range from row 1 - 50 in column A. Still no luck.. I just realized that this sheet is protected and now when i try to run the macro on that sheet it says i cant. Is there another way around this? im not sure that these sheets will allow for the use of macros

Comment: How would i go about sending it or posting it? doubt i can from these computers. Also i ran the macro using a unprotected macro-enabled file and it did work. when i try to use the same macro on the other files that are protected i get an error that i need to unprotect it to do it.

Comment: Do you not have the password for that sheet?

Comment: No i dont its a payroll sheet that we input our information onto and i just wanted to keep my own record on my own sheet by using a macro. i can always just copy and paste instead. TY for all the help though.

Comment: @SiddharthRout How does one also copy the header row?

Comment: Very instructive.  However, I'm finding that if there's existing data in the destination sheet, the last row is overwritten with the new data.  I'm wondering if `lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _ ...` should be `lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _...) + 1`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what timrau said in his comment, you can use the AutoFilter function to find the row with your name in it.  (Note that I'm assuming you have the source workbook open)

```
Dim curBook As Workbook
Dim targetBook As Workbook
Dim curSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Integer

Set curBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set curSheet = curBook.Worksheets("yourSheetName")

'change the Field number to the correct column
curSheet.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Clarke, Matthew" 

'The Offset is to remove the header row from the copy
curSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Copy  
curSheet.ShowAllData 

Set targetBook = Application.Workbooks.Open "PathTo Total Hours"
Set targetSheet = targetBook.WorkSheet("DestinationSheet")

lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row

targetSheet.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial

targetBook.Save
targetBook.Close
```

As you can see I put placeholders in for the specific setup of your workbook.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Copy ` This is an incorrect way to do it :) Please see the two links that I posted in the comment.

Comment: @Siddharth I have found that the `AutoFilter.Range` works fine.  `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` should work too, but I've had issues with it returning blank cells as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for anyone else searching for how to do this, it can be done in a much more direct fashion:

```
Public Sub ExportRow()
    Dim v
    Const KEY = "Clarke, Matthew"
    Const WS = "Sheet1"
    Const OUTPUT = "c:\totalhours.xlsx"
    Const OUTPUT_WS = "Sheet1"

    v = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(WS).Evaluate("index(a:xfd,match(""" & KEY & """,a:a,),)")
    With Workbooks.Open(OUTPUT).Sheets(OUTPUT_WS)
        .[1:1].Offset(.[counta(a:a)]) = v
        .Parent.Save: .Parent.Close
    End With
End Sub
```